# Hyperspaces of a Continuum Have no Cut Points

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

It is given as an exercise in two books of Nadler (*Continuum Theory* and *Hyperspaces of Sets*) that if $X$ is a continuum (compact, connected metric space), then $2^X$ (the set of non-empty closed subsets of $X$) and $C(X)$ (the connected subsets of $2^X$) in the Hausdorff metric have no cut points.  It is known that these spaces are path-connected.  I have had a hard time finding a reference for this.  Does anyone know of one, or how to prove it?  I have been wracking my brain on it for quite some time.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is an old result (it's in van Mill's book ""infinite-dimensional topology, prerequisites and an introduction", e.g.) that the hyperspace of a Peano continuum (connected, locally path-connected, compact metric space) is homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, which gives a lot more info.

Comment: Oh yes, a very hard theorem.  But I am working in a setting that includes some dendroids, so I can't restrict to Peano continua.

Comment: It's "easy" with the right tools... I don't know about plain metric compacta though. I'll give it a bit of thought later

Comment: J. Krasinkiewicz, "No 0-dimensional set disconnects the hyperspace of a continuum." seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I'm OK with just referencing this.  It's a sexy result!  But have you given any more thought to this case?  Given its presence as an exercise it should be more elementary.  Maybe it's a question for overflow?

Comment: Btw, I should mention that it's a theorem of Illanes that this is also true of $2^X$.  The Krasinkiewicz Theorem is only for $C(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \in C(X)$ be the point we remove.

First consider the set of all subcontinua not contained in $A$:

$\mathcal B = \{B \in C(X): B \not \subset A\}$

The order-arc theorem says each subcontinuum is at the bottom of an order-arc with $X$ as the top element. Since the arc is ordered by inclusion no element is contained in $A$. That shows $\mathcal B$ is not only connected but arc-connected.

Now let $a \in A$ be a boundary element. By definition we can find a sequence $x_n \to a$ with all $x_n \notin A$. It follows the sequence $\{x_n\} \to \{a\}$ in the hyperspace. But the sequence is contained in the component of $\mathcal B$ which is closed (in $C(X)-A$). Therefore $a$ shares a component with $\mathcal B$.

Nearly there. . . .

The subspace $\{\{b\}: b \in A\} \subset C(A)$ is a copy of $A$ and so we can throw all those $\{b\}$ into the component. Finally we can join an arbitrary subcontinuum $C \subset A$ to some $\{b\}$ by an order-arc by applying the order-arc-theoren to $C(A)$.

That proves 
$ \{B \in C(X): B \not \subset A\}$ and 
$\{C \in C(X): C \subset A\}$ share a component in $C(X)-A$.

But the two sets constitute all of $C(X)-A$. So that set is connected.

$\blacksquare$